# Can any one help me to create the function of this equation in an easy way.?

Tags: matrix, expression-construction

[image]

```
For[n = 1, n <= Ns, n++,
  x1 = 2*n*Ω/Ns;
  x2 = 2*(n - 1)*Ω/Ns;
  z = 0.5 *(x1 + x2);
  P = ω*({{0, 0, 0, μ0}, {0, 0, -μ0, 0}, {h *ϵ0* (ϵc - ϵd)* Cos[π *z/Ω + ψ] 
           Sin[π * z/Ω + ψ], -ϵ0*(ϵc * Cos[π *z/Ω + ψ]^2 + ϵd * Sin[π *z/Ω + ψ]^2), 0, 0},
            {ϵ0*(ϵc * Sin[π* z/Ω + ψ]^2 + ϵd*  Cos[π* z/Ω + ψ]^2), -h* ϵ0 *(
       ϵc - ϵd)*Cos[π *z/Ω + ψ]* Sin[π* z/Ω + ψ], 0, 0} }
       CN = MatrixExp[(I*P*2*Ω)/Ns].CN
```

where `P` is any matrix which depends on `z`, and `Nsl` is any limit, for example, 100. `Δz` is `Nsl - 2 - Nsl - 1`

Please help me.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your code; you have an unclosed parenthesis in your definition of `P`.

Comment: Your `For` expression violates _Mathematica_'s syntax rules. Please edit it so that it is syntactically correct.

Comment: What do the square brackets around `M` and the tilde mean in your LaTeX expression?

Comment: all these things are mentioned for example. leave the syntax error, i just want to know how to create the function which satisfy the formula displayed in the pic. thanks

Comment: M is just a transfer matrix , which  will be obtained by P matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to build the matrix function you want.

```
zz = Array[z, {10}];
partZZ = Partition[zz, 2, 1];
expFun[{z1_, z2_}] := MatrixExp[I delZ p[(z1 + z2)/2]];
```

Then the product of the all the terms is:

```
Times @@ (expFun[#] & /@ partZZ)
```

If you want the matrix product, replace Times with Dot. If you want it for a specific p[ ] function, then you will need to define that. For example, if

```
p[w_] := {{w, 2 w}, {3 w, 4 w}};
```

then you'll get an explicit formula for this `p[ ]`.